# How to use UITableView in Multi View application

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, uitableview, multiview

i have some other viewcontroller which triggers another viewcontroller which have UItableView as subView my code is following two file .h , .m

when i use single view based application with this code it works fine but when i use two view for examlpe 1st is logingscreen n call 2nd nib file using this

```
Viewcomment *b=[[SimpleTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SimpleTableViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:b animated:YES];
```

or

```
self.window= [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[Viewcomment alloc] initWithNibName:@"Viewcomment" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

it shows "SIGABRT" !!!
Where i am wrong ?

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SimpleTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>{
    NSArray *listData;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *listData; 

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "SimpleTableViewController.h"

@implementation SimpleTableViewController
@synthesize listData;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"iPhone", @"iPod", @"iPad",nil];
    self.listData = array;
        [super viewDidLoad];


}

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
         [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];


}

- (void)viewDidUnload {

}


- (void)dealloc {

}

#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.listData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) { cell =  [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier]   ;
    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row]; cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row]; return cell;

}


@end
```

Comment: Please reformat you question its so hard to read

Answer (score 0):

Your missing:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

from your UITableViewDataSource which will cause a crash.

If thats doesn't work make sure the view is connecting in the nib file of your view controller and make sure your UITableView is connected correctly to the data source.

Comment: thanks shoughton123 for fast reply i tried your solution  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
} i add this but still aplication get crashed !

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure if that was actually causing your crashing but it certainly would have been an issue you would have run into at some point.

Comment: it's getting crashed after - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation of target UIView sub class, i tried to set break point but can't get proper error except SIGABRT .

Comment: Yeah it sounds like the view isn't connect correctly. Go to your nib file and control drag from Files Owner to the view and make sure the view outlet is connected.